# HTMLCanvasElement : Getting Uint8ClampedArray

Tags: javascript, angular, html, typescript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to implement [this](https://github.com/eduardolundgren/tracking.js) library on an angular 7 application. For getting faces I need to convert a `canvas html dom element` to a `Uint8ClampedArray`.

Anyone knows how can I get a `Uint8ClampedArray` object from a CanvasElement?

Comment: Call `getImageData()` and then use the array it returns to populate a typed array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ctx.getImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData)  will return an ImageData object, which [`data`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData/data) property will be an Uint8ClampedArray just like your lib is requiring.

```js
const ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
ctx.canvas.width = ctx.canvas.height = 20;
ctx.fillStyle='red';
ctx.fillRect(0,0,20,20);
// get an ImageData of your whole canvas
const img = ctx.getImageData(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);
console.log(img.data instanceof Uint8ClampedArray, img.data);
// [r, g, b, a, r, g, b, a...
// [255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255...
```